# Modify item order in select field with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
    <select name="repeat_period">
    <option value="24">daily</option>
    <option value="168">weekly</option>
    </select>
```

and my goal is to remove/hide daily item for force to chose weekly. Another solution could be to invert item order and to set "readonly". In both case I don't know how to do.

PRECISION: I don't have access to html of the page. I can only use javascript for try to make modification and I don't know javascript.

Any clue ?

Comment: Did you even **try**?

Comment: Can't you at least make the effort of trying to seach first ? Because copy pasting your exact question in google yields the answer as first result

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.com).

Comment: This question probably shows the least effort of any question I've ever read on this site. It's hard to even fathom that this isn't a troll of some sort... How could you not at least have an idea of what to try or what to search for using google?

Comment: I don't have access to html..reason why I ask...and google don't return me the solution.

Comment: If you can't access the HTML, I'm not sure how you expect to manipulate it with JavaScript... It sounds like you need to provide some more details about how your project/page is set up.

Comment: The select field is located to an external site where part of his admin is integrated in my own site. I don't have any control to this html but I'm allowed to use JS in a file located to my server. I can without problem modify some element in this manner like for example make "readonly" or increase size of some specific text field. But here is matter to interact differently with a select field and I thinking this is possible to do using something like: var repeat_period = document.getElementByName('repeat_period');
repeat_period.some_code;

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed to see all people who commented my question, critic me because they think i'm too lazy for try by myself (I spent more than 2 hours in test). Everybody seem to say is something very easy to do but it seem is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I found the solution in a forum where people are more disposed to help newbie like me. If I was a guru coder, I will probably not need to ask help.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function removeIt(){
    var sel=document.getElementsByName('repeat_period')[0];
    sel.options.remove(0);
    }
    removeIt();
    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YgPw4/